# Transformations of two Laplace distributions resulting in a Laplace distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Suppose we have two independent identical  random variables  $X_1$ and $X_2$ with Laplace distribution
>   \begin{align}
> f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2b}e^{-\frac{|x|}{b}}
> \end{align} 
>   I am looking for a non-trivial transformation $Z=g(X_1,X_2)$ such that
>   $Z$ has again Laplace distribution.

Note a trivial transformation is $g(X_1,X_2)=X_1$.

A list of transformations of Laplace distribution can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution), but it does not contain the transformation we want.

This question is related to something I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1838779/transformation-of-random-variables-that-preserves-the-distribution).

Some more information on Laplace distribution can be found [here](http://www.randomservices.org/random/special/Laplace.html).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio   Note that this some is not Laplace anymore. See this post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455332/summing-laplace-random-variables

Comment: You're right, my bad. The issue here is that the CF $\frac{1}{1+b^2 t^2}$ does not stay in the same form when squared.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  It's ok I made the same mistake too. Let me know if you have any other ideas.

Comment: Are you allowing transformations $Z=g(X_1,X_2,U)$ where $U$ is a random variable independent of $(X_1,X_2)$, say, uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$?

Comment: Here is an option: $$Z=\mathrm{sign}(X_1)\cdot\left||X_1|-|X_2|\right|.$$

Comment: @Did Yes, random transformation are allowed. Thanks for the example. Any  intuition how you came up with it?

Comment: @Did  I see, how you did. Clever. $ | |X_1| -|X_2||$ is exponential  and  $ |sing(X_1)| |X_1| -|X_2||$ is Laplace.

Comment: If random transformations are allowed, you might also want to check $$Z=\mathrm{sign}(X_1)\cdot\left(|X_1|+|X_2|\right)\cdot U,$$ where $U$ is unform on $(0,1)$ and independent of $(X_1,X_2)$. (Yes, these are simply folklore results about exponential distributions.)

Comment: @Did Can you tell we what it the advantage of using  an extra random variable  $U$.   Is it to avoid  an extra absolute value?

Comment: No advantage per se, just a different option.

Comment: Another one, simpler (which was so obvious I did not even see it at first): $$Z=|X_1|-|X_2|.$$

Comment: @Did I posted another related question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842574/transformation-of-laplace-distribution-that-preserves-conditional-distribution  Maybe you will be interested.