# Transformation of Laplace distribution that preserves conditional distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose, we have a $X\sim {\rm Lap}(0,a)$ with Laplace distribution with parameter a. That is 
\begin{align}
f_X(x)= \frac{1}{2 a}e^{-|x|/a}
\end{align}

Now suppose we have two independent Laplace r.v.  $X_1\sim {\rm Lap}(0,b)$ and $X\sim {\rm Lap}(0,c)$.

I am looking for a transformation $g(X_1,X_2)$ of $X_1$ and $X_2$ such that

1. $X=g(X_1,X_2)$.  In other words this transformation results in a Laplace random variable $X\sim {\rm Lap}(0,a)$
2. Conditional pdf of $X=g(X_1,X_2)$ given $X_2$ (or $X_1$) is Laplace and given by  $f_{X|X_2}=\frac{1}{2 b}e^{-|x-\mu|/b}$ where $\mu$ is some shift parameter.

This question is motivated by the Gaussian case in which this such a transformation exists and is given by $X=X_1+X_2$.

Note that based on the previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840386/transformations-of-two-laplace-distributions-resulting-in-a-laplace-distribution),
we can deduce the transformation 
$X= a (\frac{1}{b} |X_1| -\frac{1}{c}|X_2|)$ results in Laplace random variable.

However, the second condition is not satisfied since $X|X_2$ is exponential and not Laplace.

I was thinking maybe a transformation along the lines
\begin{align}
X=  {\rm sign(X_1)}||X_1| -|X_2| |
\end{align}
possibly with scaling might do, but not sure.

Comment: Did you check $$X=  a\cdot {\rm sign}(X_1)\cdot\left|b^{-1}|X_1| -c^{-1}|X_2|\right|\ ?$$

Comment: @Did. So, $X$ is definitely Laplace. The pdf of $ | b^{-1} |X_1| -c^{-1}|X_2| |$  given $X_2=x_2$ is given by shifted exponential  $e^{-(x-x_2)}$. But not sure how to deal with $sign(X_1)$ since it is symmetric around $0$ and not around $x_2$.  Maybe, we want something like  $X=a{\rm sign} (X_1-X_2) | b^{-1} |X_1| -c^{-1}|X_2||$??